# Is there a solution to initial timeout using Dart grpc?

Tags: flutter, dart, timeout, grpc

Using Dart Grpc, I am setting the connection timeout to 5 seconds. While this does appear to work to a degree, the initial timeout periods vary considerably. eg: 30 sec, 28 sec, 64 sec. After the initial timeout (no connection), the timeouts are consistently 3 seconds, but the first is always much longer. Is there some way that I can improve this, because the initial wait time is too long? Without setting a timeout at all, the connection appears to never timeout.
Code is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';

import 'protos/counter1.pb.dart';
import 'protos/counter1.pbgrpc.dart';

  _fnOnBuildComplete() async {
    try {
      _vChannel = ClientChannel('192.168.1.5',
          port: 8080,
          options: const ChannelOptions(
              credentials: ChannelCredentials.insecure(),
              connectionTimeout: Duration(seconds: 5)));
      _vChannel.getConnection().timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
      _vClient = Counter1Client(_vChannel);
      _vClient..fnIncrementCounter(Counter1Request()..req1 = "0") /* INIT */;
    } catch (vError) {
      print("_fnOnBuildComplete: Error = $vError");
    }
  }
```

Typical Error is:

```
I/flutter (16490): _fnIncrementCounter: error = gRPC Error (14, Error connecting: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 192.168.1.5, port = 33823)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello from the future!

It looks like the `dart-grpc` maintainers have recently added a `connectTimeout` parameter to `ChannelOptions` (different from the existing `connectionTimeout`) in [Dec 2022](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/commit/60311a74926743c5e35caa0bd718f05a9b40e914).

Example:

```dart
  ...
  channelOptions = const ChannelOptions(
      credentials: ChannelCredentials.insecure(),
      connectTimeout: Duration(seconds: 5), // initial connect
      connectionTimeout: Duration(seconds: 5) // 
    ),
  ...
```

At the time of this writing, it hasn't made it into a published version, but you could try it like so:

pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
dependencies:  
  ...
  grpc: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart.git
      ref: 60311a74926743c5e35caa0bd718f05a9b40e914
  ...
```